# 'No bluetooth found' Error

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I've been trying to find a fix for two days, don't even remember everything I've tried.  This post is my last resort. And I'm perfectly fine tyring everything again :D

- HP laptop model: 15-n205TX
- Dual Booted: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Bluetooth Works fine on Windows 10.
- Fast Startup disabled.

`lsusb` results

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'll keep updating this post with your solutions and its result. Please keep in mind I'm a noob. Thanks!

Comment: Start by disabling Fast Startup in Windows and shutdown properly.

Comment: Also please add output of `lsusb`.